# loop has no effect on specific array element

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix

I'm trying to invert a 3x3 matrix. I gauss the augment that has both the original and the identity matrix. Depending on the matrix dimensions, the identity matrix is generated by a separate function with 1s along the main diagonal and 0s everywhere else. Once the operations are complete, the original matrix should be an identity and the identity should be the inverse. I'm able to successfully turn the original into an identity but the something is preventing the original identity from fully becoming the inverse which is confusing because both arrays are inside the same loops.

```
const int m = 3;
const int n = 3;

double matrix[m][n];
double ID[m][n] = {};

double pivot;

for(s = 1;s <= m;++s){
    pivot = matrix[s-1][s-1];
    k = s + 1;

    for(i = n;i >= 1;--i){                    // makes leading entries 1

            ID[s-1][i-1] = ID[s-1][i-1]/pivot;
            matrix[s-1][i-1] = matrix[s-1][i-1]/pivot;

        }

        for(j = k;j <= m;++j){             //converts to upper triangular

            for(i = n;i >= 1;--i){       

                ID[j-1][i-1] = ID[j-1][i-1] - ID[s-1][i-1]*matrix[j-1][s-1];    //*****<--- has no effect on ID[2][0]
                matrix[j-1][i-1] = matrix[j-1][i-1] - matrix[s-1][i-1]*matrix[j-1][s-1];

            }

        }

} //ID[2][0] = 0; <--- gives correct answer when uncommented

    for(s = m;s >= 1;--s){

        k = s - 1;

        for(j = k;j >= 1;--j){             //makes entries above diagonal zero

            for(i = 1;i <= n;++i){

                ID[j-1][i-1] = ID[j-1][i-1] - ID[s-1][i-1]*matrix[j-1][s-1];
            matrix[j-1][i-1] = matrix[j-1][i-1] - matrix[s-1][i-1]*matrix[j-1][s-1];

            }

        }

}
```

Here's the process by hand, the big arrow points to where I believe my code is getting stuck. `ID[2][0]` remains as -1 which in turn prevents `ID[0][0]` from being set to -3 over the final loop.

[method with correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkmtB.jpg)

[result without forcing ID(2)[0] to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFcyL.jpg)

[result forcing ID(2)[0] to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GevL.jpg)

I don't understand what is going wrong as the loop works fine on `matrix[m][n]`.

Comment: Why are you starting all your loops at 1 and then subtracting 1? `for(s = 1;s <= m;++s){
    pivot = matrix[s-1][s-1];` Don't you think it would be easier to read like this `for(s = 0;s < m;++s){
    pivot = matrix[s][s];`? You may not like it, but you should get used to the fact that arrays start at 0 in C++ and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: A debugger will quickly tell you what the problem is. I wouldn't be surprised if you got one of your indexes wrong. But fire up the debugger and step through the code. You'll find the problem very quickly if you know how to use a debugger, and if not then think of this as an ideal oppotunity to learn an extremely useful skill.